# How to display a nested array in a template

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, nested

I'm trying to iterate in a array nested in an other array.
My collection data :

```
 "roles" : [
    {
        "id" : 126987,
        "name" : "Ergonomic Wooden Fish",
        "containers" : [
                 {
                     "id" : "2654213845" ,
                     "name" : "FirstCont",
                     "rights" : [
                        {
                            "id" : "54684213",
                            "name: "FirstRight"

                        }
                       ]
            }
          ]
   }
 ]
```

JS/Helpers

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  'roles': function() {
   return Roles.find({});
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<template name='myTemplate'>
  {{#each roles}}
     {{id}}
     {{name}}
     {{#each containers}}
        {{name}}
     {{/each}}
   {{/each}}
</template>
```

I can display `name` and `id` from `roles`, but not `name` from `containers`.

I try to visualize the object back but I can't.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create another helper `containers`.

```
containers: function(){
     return this.containers;
 }
```

and then keep your template as it is.

```
<template name='myTemplate'>
{{#each roles}}
 {{id}}
 {{name}}
 {{#each containers}}
    {{name}}
 {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```